# How to manipulate data base on table information in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

Very new in SSIS , have two table One is **BaseTable** another one is **Condition** Table,Base table record will be update base on condition table information.

Base table
[image]

Condition table
[image]

Base table with desired data
[image]

Is it possible in SSIS?

Comment: write the query based on status type and product type  and put in SQL task it will do the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use an `Execute SQL Task` after you inserted your values to base table and condition table you can use an update statement

```
  update [dbo].[base]
  set producttypename = b.value,
  statuscode = c.value
  FROM [dbo].[base] a
  left join [dbo].[condition] b on a.Producttype = b.[key] and 
  b.sourcefield = 'producttype'
  left join [dbo].[condition] c on a.statustype = c.[key] and 
  c.sourcefield = 'statustype'
```

**Result**

[image]

Comment: as you see my condition table column SourceTable have many tables so i need to write many tasks,is it possible to consolidate in one task?

Comment: You only need one? Just add the extra tables in your joines. Make it dynamic if you have really many

Comment: you can write multiple update statements in 1 `Exec SQL Task` separated by `GO` . eg `update...from...where GO update...from...where GO`